# Exclude Namespaces from being managed by an operator

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk

In this chapter of `operator-sdk` documentation: https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/operator-scope/#watching-resources-in-a-set-of-namespaces, following sentence is not clear to me:
*'IMPORTANT: Note that this is not intended to be used for excluding Namespaces, this is better done via a Predicate.'*

Could you please provide an example which excludes Namespaces from being managed by an operator?

Comment: the [`Options`'s](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/manager#Options) struct has a `Namespace` field which describes `// Namespace if specified restricts the manager's cache to watch objects in the desired namespace Defaults to all namespaces`, so based on the description, if we set the `Namespace` to a particular namespace name then it will only watch objects in that namespace.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaChaurasia, this is clear to me. What I'd like is the operator to watch all namespace except one, or a few ones. The documentation recommends using a predicate for this but does not explain how. That is what I want to know.

Comment: Here is a different doc that explains how to do [event filtering based on the predicate](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/references/event-filtering/#using-predicates) so based on the value of the namespace(s), you can decide to skip the events.

Comment: basically in the setup operation in `SetupWithManager`, we add the `WithEventFilter()` and pass a function to it which has the filtering logic in it. the above example shows how to ignore the deletion events, similarly we can write our own event filtering to ignore the events based on the value of a namespace we want to ignore the events.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia would you please have some examples of events based on a namespace and how to exclude them, This is not clear to me.

Comment: the event filtering is done based on the truthy value of the predicate function, for example `return e.MetaOld.GetGeneration() != e.MetaNew.GetGeneration()` returns true only when the generation of old object and new object are not same and the event is ignored in all other cases. you can create a similar method to return `False` based on the condition `if e.MetaNew.Namespace in [list_of_namespace_to_skip]` then any time an event is generated for an object in these namespaces, you filter them here and don't enter the reconcile loop.